# How to convert and ADT ArrayBag to an ADT VectorBag?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, abstract-data-type, bag

I need to convert the following ADT Bag from using arrays to using vectors.  I have been trying to do this, but have been unable to get the program to work.  How would I change this?

header file

```
#ifndef _ARRAY_BAG
#define _ARRAY_BAG

#include "BagInterface.h"

template<class ItemType>
class ArrayBag : public BagInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
    static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 6; // Small size to test for a full bag
    ItemType items[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];      // Array of bag items
   int itemCount;                         // Current count of bag items 
   int maxItems;                          // Max capacity of the bag

   // Returns either the index of the element in the array items that
   // contains the given target or -1, if the array does not contain 
   // the target.
   int getIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const;   

public:
    ArrayBag();
    int getCurrentSize() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
    bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
    void clear();
    bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
    int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
   vector<ItemType> toVector() const;
}; // end ArrayBag

#include "ArrayBag.cpp"
#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include "ArrayBag.h"
#include <cstddef>

template<class ItemType>
ArrayBag<ItemType>::ArrayBag(): itemCount(0), maxItems(DEFAULT_CAPACITY)
{
}  // end default constructor

template<class ItemType>
int ArrayBag<ItemType>::getCurrentSize() const
{
    return itemCount;
}  // end getCurrentSize

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return itemCount == 0;
}  // end isEmpty

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    bool hasRoomToAdd = (itemCount < maxItems);
    if (hasRoomToAdd)
    {
        items[itemCount] = newEntry;
        itemCount++;
    }  // end if

    return hasRoomToAdd;
}  // end add

/*
// STUB
 template<class ItemType>
 bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& anEntry)
 {
    return false; // STUB
 }  // end remove
*/   

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& anEntry)
{
   int locatedIndex = getIndexOf(anEntry);
    bool canRemoveItem = !isEmpty() && (locatedIndex > -1);
    if (canRemoveItem)
    {
        itemCount--;
        items[locatedIndex] = items[itemCount];
    }  // end if

    return canRemoveItem;
}  // end remove

/*
 // STUB
 template<class ItemType>
 void ArrayBag<ItemType>::clear()
 {
    // STUB
 }  // end clear
*/

template<class ItemType>
void ArrayBag<ItemType>::clear()
{
    itemCount = 0;
}  // end clear

template<class ItemType>
int ArrayBag<ItemType>::getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
   int frequency = 0;
   int curIndex = 0;       // Current array index
   while (curIndex < itemCount)
   {
      if (items[curIndex] == anEntry)
      {
         frequency++;
      }  // end if

      curIndex++;          // Increment to next entry
   }  // end while

   return frequency;
}  // end getFrequencyOf

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
    return getIndexOf(anEntry) > -1;
}  // end contains

/* ALTERNATE 1: First version
template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& target) const 
{
   return getFrequencyOf(target) > 0;
}  // end contains

// ALTERNATE 2: Second version 
template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
   bool found = false;
   int curIndex = 0;        // Current array index
   while (!found && (curIndex < itemCount))
   {
      if (anEntry == items[curIndex])
      {
         found = true;
      } // end if

      curIndex++;           // Increment to next entry
   }  // end while   

   return found;
}  // end contains
*/

template<class ItemType>
vector<ItemType> ArrayBag<ItemType>::toVector() const
{
    vector<ItemType> bagContents;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        bagContents.push_back(items[i]);

   return bagContents;
}  // end toVector

// private
template<class ItemType>
int ArrayBag<ItemType>::getIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const
{
    bool found = false;
   int result = -1;
   int searchIndex = 0;

   // If the bag is empty, itemCount is zero, so loop is skipped
   while (!found && (searchIndex < itemCount))
   {
      if (items[searchIndex] == target)
      {
         found = true;
         result = searchIndex;
      } 
      else
      {
         searchIndex++;
      }  // end if
   }  // end while

   return result;
}  // end getIndexOf
```